# How will i set a sql query as a variable in vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

```
    Private Sub btncalc_Click(Sender,e)
    a = val(txtConcode.Text)
    b = val(txtConsumed.Text)
    If a = 1 Then
    Dim cmd as new mysqlcommand
    cmd.connection = con
    connect()
    cmd.CommandText = "select Rate from tblrate where ConvertID=1"
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    if dr.Read Then
    q = dr.Read
    end if
    disconnect()
```

what i want to know is, how could i get the value from my sql query
and transfer it to the variable q
i just created the dr thing for example

Comment: look into using parameterized queries, which you could then get your value from a `SqlParameter` object.  If you only expect one result, you could also look into `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`, which will return the first column of the first record returned.

Comment: for more background ive created a billing system, now the value of a is the code wherein i compare it to the convertid, the tbl rate has records which specify what number must be multiplied to the b which is the consumed bill.. now i want to extract the value in the Rate store it in q and later use it to multiply to b so that i could get the bill......

Comment: With OleDBAdapter you can use DataTable variable ...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062167/how-to-display-query-results-from-sql-server-in-vb

Comment: @PM77-1 i dont intend to display the query results, rather i want to get its value and store it in another variable. . any help please

Comment: @ps2goat how would i convert the value of dr  into string so that i can store it in another variable?

Comment: Please help me, anyone

Comment: Dim result = dr("column")