# Asp.net + Call function within function

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, function

I have a function in asp.net vb class file which generates a unique alphanumeric string.

After generating the string, I want to check if the string already exists in sql table, if so, I want to repeat the process.

Please find the code I am using

```
    Public Function GenerateUniqueID() As String    
     Dim numbers As String = "1234567890"
     Dim characters As String = numbers
     Dim length As Integer = 5
     Dim UID As String = String.Empty
     For i As Integer = 0 To length - 1
        Dim character As String = String.Empty
        Do
            Dim index As Integer = New Random().Next(0, characters.Length)
            character = characters.ToCharArray()(index).ToString()
        Loop While otp.IndexOf(character) <> -1
        UID += character
     Next

  '-----------
  check if UID already exist in db
  if yes

     repeat same function to generate new ID

  if no

     return unique id

   '-----------
     Return UID
End Function
```

I want to know how can I call same function if generated ID already exist in database.

Comment: So, what did you try?

Comment: Is your question _"how do I query a SQL server in VB.NET"_?

Comment: make your question more clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display query results from SQL server in VB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062167/how-to-display-query-results-from-sql-server-in-vb)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating the random string on the front end, try it in SQL Server itself. Try the following

```
DECLARE @UID NVARCHAR(255),@Row INT =0

WHILE ISNULL(@Row,0) =0
BEGIN
    SELECT @UID = NEWID()
    SELECT @Row = COUNT(1) FROM YourTable WHERE AlphaString = @UID

END

SELECT AlphaString = @UID
```

Comment: I want to show a user friendly ID to user before saving to database. Like Ticket No : FH87-KJ98923. There should not be a duplicate for this ID in the table.

Comment: I have updated the answer, now it will return you a new id that does not exists in the table and return the value, you can display it to customer and insert it to the table once the customer approves

Comment: Sorry, the query is not executing. It is taking a long time.

Comment: @user7566865I removed 1 line accidentally, I've added that back, try now

Comment: what is NEW_ID, it is showing error. I have a function to generate unique id, is it possible to check that value against database and call same function repeatedly.

Comment: it's NEWID which is an inbuilt function in SQL Server to generate a Random unique string. If you want to use your function, then you will have to generate the id using the function and loop checking the database until you find a nonexisting id, it will Increase the load on both application as well as Database Server, which can affect all users using the Application or DB Server

Comment: Showing Invalid column name 'NEWID'. I have edited my post with the code I am using.

Comment: Same problem, it is executing continuously

Comment: That's Why I told you, but I don't think you will need the existence check as newid() generates random unique string, or else you can create a column with uniqueidentifier data type which will generate globally unique values

Comment: Can we restrict character length of NEWID() string.

Comment: just use left or substring